# Why do referees raise their arm on three-point field goals?

Tags: rules, nba

While watching a highlight video of three-point field goals in the NBA, I noticed the referees raise their arm after the ball leaves the shooter's hands and through the duration of three-point field goals. **Why do referees raise their arm on three-point field goals?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the NBA, WNBA, NCAA and internationally under FIBA rules, the referee is required to raise his arm when a three point field goal is being attempted. If the player on the court makes the three point field goal, the referee is required to hold up his other hand to signal to the score keeper that the player has made the field goal. The actual signal differs slightly between the NBA and WNBA, where the referee is simply required to raise their hand(s), and the NCAA and FIBA rules where the referee is required to raise their hand(s) with three fingers extended.

This video gives a visual explanation of the three point shot hand signal: [VIDEO](http://www.ehow.co.uk/video_2355374_signaling-3-point-shot-basketball.html)

---

The NBA signal can be seen on page 66 the [2013-2014 Rule Book](http://www.nba.com/.element/mp3/2.0/sect/podcastmp3/NBA/podcast/2013-14-Rule-Book.pdf):

[image: Referee during three point shot]

The FIBA signal can be seen on page 58 of the [2014 Official Basketball Rules](http://www.fiba.com/downloads/Rules/2014/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf).

Comment: The key words being "to signal to the score keeper".  That's really the intention behind most signals.  Signals weren't originally made for audience understanding, but to communicate between officials, and in certain circumstances to notify players\teams.  Note how many signals in https://www.nfhs.org/media/1015648/basketball-signal-chart.pdf show something a scorer\timer would need to know, and how wildly different\exaggerated competing signals are.
The score keeper is not allowed to judge whether it was worth 2 or 3 (or make any judgements at all), only rely upon the signal of the referees.